# Sistema de apontamentos [params]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

Estou criando um sistema de apontamentos com clientes, projetos, atividades, profissionais e apontamento, todas as partes passam e salvam corretamente, menos a parte do lançamento dos apontamentos.

Segue a imagem do erro ao tentar realizar o apontamento.

[image: Erro apontamento]

Segue o código do new.html.erb

```html
<%= form_for (@timesheet), html:{ class: "form-horizontal" } do |f| %>

<!-- Alert Error -->
<%= error_messages_for @timesheet %>
<!-- Title -->
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :activity_id, "Atividade:", class: "control-label col-sm-2" %>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9">
    <%= collection_select(:timesheet, :activity_id, Activity.all, :object_id, :name) %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :professional, "Profissional:", class: "control-label col-sm-2" %>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9">
    <%= collection_select(:timesheet, :professional, Professional.all, :user_id, :name) %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :day, "Dia:", class: "control-label col-sm-2" %>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-9">
    <%= f.text_field :initial_hour, :class => 'form-control date', placeholder: 'DD/MM/AAAA' %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :initial_hour, "Data/Hora Inicial:", class: "control-label col-sm-2" %>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9">
    <%= f.time_select :initial_hour, :class => 'form-control', :required => true %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :final_hour, "Data/Hora Final:", class: "control-label col-sm-2" %>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9">
    <%= f.time_select :final_hour, :class => 'form-control', :required => true %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :quantity_hours, "Quantidade de horas:", class: "control-label col-sm-2" %>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-9">
    <%= f.text_field :quantity_hours, :class => 'form-control', :required => true %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :situation, "Situação:", class: "control-label col-sm-2" %>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9">
    <%= f.select :status, Timesheet.status.options %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :remunerated, "Remunerado:", class: "control-label col-sm-2" %>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9">
    <%= f.check_box :remunerated, :class => 'form-control', :required => true %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :billed, "Faturado:", class: "control-label col-sm-2" %>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9">
    <%= f.check_box :billed, :class => 'form-control', :required => true %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :displacement, "Deslocamento:", class: "control-label col-sm-2" %>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9">
    <%= f.check_box :displacement, :class => 'form-control', :required => true %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>

<!-- Buttons -->
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
    <%= link_to "Cancelar", timesheets_path, :class => 'btn btn-white' %>
    <%= f.submit "Salvar", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
</div>

<% end %>
```

PS: Sou novo no rails e estou meio perdido.
PS²: Estou usando enumerize para definir os options nos status.

Answer (score 0):

O erro ocorre porque o model está esperando receber um objeto `Professional` para seu atributo `.professional`, mas está recebendo uma `String`, que creio ser o `id` desse `collection_select`, tente alterar em seu form para que o valor seja inserido em `professional_id`. Tente deste modo:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :professional_id, "Profissional:", class: "control-label col-sm-2" %>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9">
    <%= collection_select(:timesheet, :professional_id, Professional.all, :user_id, :name) %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Dúvida: esse campo `:user_id` é o `id` do `Professional`, não sei como é seu modelo de negócio, mas normalmente utiliza-se o campo `id` mesmo.